# Django: request.user.user_permissions is always None

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have created a user and assigned it to a group from django admin panel. I have given certain permissions to that group. However, when I catch the request in my view, it seems that the associated user has no permission at all. I'm using JWT web token based authentication system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user_permissions` just contains the permissions explicitly assigned to the user. To also get those that are implicitly assigned as part of group membership, you need to use [`get_all_permissions()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_all_permissions).

Comment: hay man, if u have a little time, im aprecciate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731384/custom-user-return-empty-get-all-permissions?noredirect=1#comment125044013_70731384