# Custom User return empty get_all_permissions()

Tags: django, authentication, permissions

I'm just trying start work with `Permissions` to learn how thats work.

In shell i have empty `set()` result from `user_test.get_all_permissions()`. I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081061/django-user-get-all-permissions-is-empty-while-user-permissions-is-set), is the same of that, but i can't find what is missing im my code:

**Edit**

Now seeing in [class ModelBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend), a particular part confuses my mind: `...get_all_permissions(),...allow an object to be passed as a parameter for object-specific permissions, but this backend does not implement them other than returning an empty set of permissions if` **obj is not None**

And bellow in docs:

**get_all_permissions(user_obj, obj=None)**

`Returns the set of permission strings the user_obj has, including both user permissions and group permissions. Returns an empty set if is_anonymous or is_active is False.`

My user have `is_active flag=true`, even though `user_test.get_all_permissions()` return empty `set()`.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115558/user-object-has-no-attribute-get-all-permissions#comment115119224_65115558) question a comment call my atention:
"You need to implement a `get_all_permissions` in your User model..."

I'm lost in this general understanding that part of `Permissions` concept.

I created `Custom User` from `AbstractBaseUser`, with follow code:

settings.py

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'users.backends.CustomModelBackend',
]
...
```

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, phone, password = None):
    ...
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, phone, password = None):
    ...

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    objects = UserManager()
    ...
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

backends.py

```
class CustomModelBackend(backends.ModelBackend):
    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        return True
```

In `shell` i try something like:

```
>>> from users.models import User
>>> user_test = User.objects.get(email="user@example.com")
>>> user_test.get_all_permissions()
set()
```

That `user` is `superuser`. And i test it to regular user to

**EDIT**

I realized that I might need to implement this in the backend, I don't know if it's the correct path, but making the following change I get the following error:

backends.py edit

```
from django.contrib.auth import backends

def _user_get_permissions(user, obj, from_name):
    permissions = set()
    name = 'get_%s_permissions' % from_name
    for backend in backends.get_backends():
        if hasattr(backend, name):
            permissions.update(getattr(backend, name)(user, obj))
    return permissions

class CustomModelBackend(backends.ModelBackend):
    
    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        return True
    
    def _get_user_permissions(self, user_obj):
        return user_obj.user_permissions.all()
    
    def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return _user_get_permissions(self, obj, 'all')
```

The error:

```
...
line 198, in _user_get_permissions
    permissions.update(getattr(backend, name)(user, obj))
TypeError: get_all_permissions() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What is needed to check that permissions?

Comment: You don't need `user` argument remove it like this: `getattr(backend, name)(obj)`

Comment: tks for atention, Idk, it seems like ignore my backend or whatever... >>> from users.models import User
>>> user_test = User.objects.get(email="user@example.com")
>>> user_test.get_all_permissions()`

Comment: Have you tried what i suggested ?

Comment: @Ahtisham ` File "/home/noot/.virtualenvs/masterEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 285, in get_all_permissions
    return _user_get_permissions(self, obj, 'all')
  File "/home/noot/.virtualenvs/masterEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 198, in _user_get_permissions
    permissions.update(getattr(backend, name)(user, obj))
TypeError: get_all_permissions() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: @Ahtisham yeah, above the error

Comment: You have not removed the user argument yet remove it from getattr.

Comment: @Ahtisham this is what i say... seems like django ignore my backend... and use contrib... i do what u say `permissions.update(getattr(backend, name)(obj))`

Comment: @Ahtisham idk if is relevant, but i use `class UsersAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
...
kadmin = UsersAdminSite(name='kadmin')`

Answer (score 0):

For superuser this list would be empty. On has_perm method there is IF for superuser and its always return True for superuser

Comment: tks for atention, i test it to regular user too...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had my custom User class, and I was trying to use [djago-jazzmin](https://django-jazzmin.readthedocs.io/) for admin panel. I was getting error because I didn't have `get_all_permissions` method on my custom User model. Implementing stated method as below solved my problem and I was able to successfully load jazzmin admin:

```
def get_all_permissions(user=None):
    if user.is_superadmin:
        
        return set()
```